# How can I get Terminal to accept mouse clicks the way PuTTY does (eg inside elinks)?

Tags: terminal

When running ncurses-based tools like elinks, PuTTY (for Windows) allows you to click on links.

However, in Terminal, you need to navigate via keyboard.

Is there a way to get Terminal to pass-through clicks the way PuTTY does? If not, is there a terminal emulator for OS X that will do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question (I don't know PuTTY). Do You want to click on the links/URLs? Or You want to place Your text cursor in the place You clicked? If You mean the secon option, try `ALT`+`Click`

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek - PuTTY lets you click on the links in elinks (and lynx, and some others), and then elinks processes it as if you had keyboard navigated to the link and pressed <enter>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible on Terminal app. But, if you want this functionality you should try a Terminal alternative like [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com), where you can do it with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + click.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal App support open default App locally,
<kbd>⌘</kbd> + Double Click on a URL in Terminal.app (OS X 10.5: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + Double Click).

@jherran is right,
iTerm2 provide the feature you want and even support trackpad scroll gesture

Comment: I don't want to open it *locally* - I want to open the link in elinks which I already have running side my ssh session :)

Comment: oops I made a mistake, sorry. iTerm2 native support it and even support trackpad scroll gesture

Comment: I will change my answer

Comment: though the ⌘-doubleclick is a neat trick I'd not known before (and this after being a Mac Guy(tm) for the last nearly 30 years!)